# How to restrict the type ahead option to select from the keyboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, typeahead.js

I have a type ahead for my input as follows,

```
<input
  typeahead-template-url="app/templates/type-a-head-item.html"
  type="text"
  ng-model="selectedDisease"
  search-head="powerSearch"
  typeahead-loading="loadingLocations"
  typeahead-wait-ms="200"
  typeahead-min-length="0"
  placeholder="Disease, Procedure or Medicine"
  typeahead="match as match._source.name for match in getDiseases($viewValue)"
  typeahead-focus-first="false"
  typeahead-editable="false" 
  typeahead-loading="loadingDiseases"
  class="form-control input-lg ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required magnifyInput Bcolor"
  typeahead-on-select="searchDoctors()"
  aria-autocomplete="list"
  aria-expanded="false"
  aria-owns="typeahead-12-6891">
```

I want to select the option only from the drop down but not by selecting it with keyboard enter.I tried lot of methods with jQuery but none worked.Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});
```

Comment: 'I tried lot of methods' => Try to share.

Comment: @mt1: is your issue resolved... ? If you have found a solution then you can share with us... :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this attribute should achieve your desired behavior:

```
typeahead-should-select="false"
```

From the [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/):

> **typeahead-should-select($event)** (Default: null)
>
> A callback executed when a keyup event that might trigger a selection occurs.
>   Selection will only occur if this function returns true.

Comment: Hi marsze,i just put typeahead-should-select="false" but not working

Comment: @mt1 I tried it myself and it worked just as expected. Define "not working" or clarify your desired behavior.

Comment: Actually i just pasted the line 'typeahead-should-select="false"' in my input and ddid not made any changes but the behaviour of the typeahead did not change.Do I need to change anything else.

Comment: @mt1 Read the documentation. I have provided the link already. You should understand what you are doing. This is something we cannot do for you.

Comment: @mt1 Maybe the rest of your configuration interferes in some way. But I don't know enough about it. My solution is THE correct way to do it, according to the docs. But you'll have to try it yourself.

Comment: @marsze The docs mention nothing at all about providing a string to this attribute. It expects a callback, they say. Providing a string may or may not do what you expect, but is definitely not "THE correct way to do it, according to the docs".

Comment: @DanielM The docs say it expects an angular expression. All attribute values are strings of course. I suppose you can provide either the function call or the expression directly, like in other angular directives. But feel free to add your own answer with a working solution.

Comment: You even quoted it. It says that you must pass "a callback", not an Angular expression.

Comment: @DanielM You can only define strings as values for attribute. The round '$' icon in the docs indicates that for that attribute, the value is interpreted as an angular expression. An angular expression can be a function call ("callback"), which is apparently expected for this attribute. Please stop making rude comments.